# How can I print a specific field with an expression using awk -F?

Tags: ubuntu, awk, grep

I am trying to print only e-mail addresses from a file, file format is as follows:

```
{"12":"34","email":"johnsmith@gmail.com","firstname":"john","lastname":"smith","text":"0","sig":"js","..":"2017-08-23"}
```

How can I just extract using awk -F? So I can use awk -F'"' '{print $8}' but the 8th column may not always be the e-mail address.

Is there a way to use awk -F WITH a regular expression of '@'?
Or print all texts in the delimiter in separate lines then pipe it to | grep '@'

Thanks

Comment: If awk isn't a strict requirement, you could write a small script using language which includes a json parser (such as python).

Comment: Better use jq, which will permit you to get the value of attribute "email"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an `awk` way.

```
awk -v RS=\" '/@/' infile.txt
```

The above is correct when you have quoted fields, else you should have RS with multiple RecordSeperators. like `RS='[[:blank:]]*:'` per your sample in your comment.

Comment: I get `12:34 email:johnsmith@gmail.com firstname:john lastname:smith text:0 sig:js ..:2017-08-23` with this :-(

Comment: so where is the quotes there you have in your shared sample in body of your question? if no quotes change RS to `RS='[[:blank:]]*:'` to get it to work, also I don't suggest to use awk where there is correct [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/) tool for that

Answer (score 1):

***[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/)*** is a proper tool for parsing/manipulating json data:

```
jq '.email' jsonfile
```

The output:

```
"johnsmith@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Add - r to be rid of the quotes.

Comment: @Kusalananda, you shouldn't decide instead of OP. If the OP will mention about that requirement - it'll be added

Comment: Sorry, my intention was to mean "if you want to be rid of the quotes (in the output)", not a critique on the answer as such. jq is definitely the correct solution here.

Comment: `jq` is only the correct answer to the question: _How can I print a specific field_.  It is not the answer to this question, which specifically asks how it is done using `awk`.

Comment: @garethTheRed, even if the question is "How can I just extract using awk -F from JSON". - using awk for json is a bad practice, fragile solution and a bad advice for the future

Comment: @garethTheRed IMHO, asking how to build a chair with a screwdriver warrants an answer that explains how to do it using the correct tools. What this answer lacks is just an explanation of why parsing structured datasets without a parser that understands its structure is a bad thing.

Comment: @Kusalananda - assuming the person has a tool other than a screwdriver. The OP may not have access to `jq` and has to work with `awk`.  Surely _use jq_ should be a comment and maybe a link to a question/answer on how to use it to extract data?

Comment: The intention is to use awk or something similar that is already installed. Script will be used on many servers, where awk would be more convenient rather than installing the jq package.

Answer (score 0):

The reg-ex may need tweaking to be fully compliant with RFC 5322, but as a starter, try:

```
awk '{match($0,"[a-zA-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-z0-9._%+-]",a)}END{print a[0]}'
```